# Trying to delete a blob in Azure Functions but DeleteIfExists method is missing

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I created a new C# Azure Function with a blob trigger with the BlobTrigger template. Then I changed the type of the blob trigger binding to CloudBlockBlob. Next I tried adding a line to delete the blob. What that resulted in was a function compilation error:

```
[Error] run.csx(8,12): error CS1061: 'CloudBlockBlob' does not contain a definition for 'DeleteIfExists' and no extension method 'DeleteIfExists' accepting a first argument of type 'CloudBlockBlob' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

What am I missing? According to the documentation CloudBlockBlob should have a method called DeleteIfExists.

Here is my entire function:

```
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"

using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;

public static void Run(CloudBlockBlob myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Properties.Length} Bytes");
    myBlob.DeleteIfExists();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on Functions v2, then you are probably using .NET Core or .NET Standard, which seems to support only the async methods. Use `await myblob.DeleteIfExistsAsync()` instead.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. I did not notice .NET Core or .NET Standard didn't have the synchronous method.